# Mongo db database created using c# code is not visible in terminal

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying mongo db using .net core and .net driver using visual studio code in my linux machine. I am able to create dbs, use dbs, query them everything I can do with my terminal. But the DBs I am creating with the .net driver from my code is not visible when I view from console. What could be the reason for this?

This is the code I am using.

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoDBDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoClient client=new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            var db=client.GetDatabase("BookStore");
            var collection=db.GetCollection<Book>("Book");
            Book book=new Book();
            book.Title="Test Book1";
            book.ISBN="123123213123";
            book.Publisher="I am not a publisher";
            collection.InsertOneAsync(book);
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public ObjectId Id{get;set;}
        public string ISBN{get;set;}
        public string Title{get;set;}
        public string Publisher{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the collection, because it's not created, and it's not created because you use an asynchronous method to insert it. It will be inserted into the collection (and collection will be created) if you simply use `collection.InsertOne` instead.

Comment: But I can see the DB using compas.